# How can I have a single layout look different in landscape vs portrait?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a full-screen dialog with a vertical layout that works well in portrait mode. But of course it's too tall vertically in landscape mode. It looks roughly like this:

```
1. a few rows of text
2. a screen-width image
3. some buttons and checkboxes
4. a button at the bottom
```

In landscape, I'd like item 2 to be, say, 50% of the screen width, with item 3 to its right. And I want this to be handled while the dialog is showing.

I know I can create a 2nd layout, and switch between them upon rotation. But, is there a way to do this with only one layout, using a flow or constraint approach?

Answer (score 1):

> But, is there a way to do this with only one layout, using a flow or constraint approach?

You could adjust things programmatically. But really "create a 2nd layout" is the Android way to handle this problem.